# PERL5.26.1 eval tr operator with interpolation (example on p 76 of camel book) does not work

Tags: perl, eval, tr

trying to use a variable as a pattern in a tr operator statement.
The camel book p.76 says to use eval like so:

```
eval "tr/$oldlist/$newlist/";
```

Using perl_5.26.1 on Linux there are two things wrong with that:
a) using quotes as above eval gives an error message.
So you must put it in a block using braces.
b) even in braces it does not work. What am I doing wrong? here is the code and ouput:

```
    $kards = -99;
    $bad="AKQJT98765432KKKK";
    $card='K';
    eval {print "eval is testing for $card in $bad \n"; 
           $kards = $bad =~ tr/$card//; # tried also tr/$card/$card/; same result.
          };
    print "Num of $card in $bad = $kards \n";
    $king = $bad =~ tr/K//;
    print "Num of K in $bad is = $king \n";
=cut    
    Returns the following:
eval is testing for K in AKQJT98765432KKKK 
Num of K in AKQJT98765432KKKK = 0 
Num of K in AKQJT98765432KKKK is = 5 
    
=end
```

Comment: Gives what error message? What are your values for those variables?

Comment: It's worth noting that `eval` should be your **tool of absolute last resort** as it can cause a whole lot of problems if applied incorrectly, something that is exceedingly easy to do.

Comment: @tadman Nah... Not if you try to mimic OOP. `eval { stuff that might die(); } if($@) { ...`

`eval` is the `try` in that respect.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, that form's fine, but arbitrary string interpolation is bad news.

Comment: @tadman 100% agreement

Comment: It honestly shouldn't let you use tainted values inside of `eval` but it's far too late to fix that.

Comment: Going into "tainting" when it comes to perl becomes almost a different language :-)

Comment: That example in Camel (p.157 in my 3rd Ed.) assumes that there is `$_` defined, to which it binds the `tr` (so, it's `$_ =~ tr///`). If there isn't a defined `$_` at that point in the code then you get a warning; shouldn't get an error for that.

Comment: The Camel Book told you to use `eval EXPR`, but you used `eval BLOCK`. Not the same thing!

Answer (score 3):

You want to remove a set of characters from a string via `tr` where that set is determined at runtime, and get how many of those characters were removed?

Since `tr` doesn't do variable interpolation as noted in [the documentation](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr) and the Programming Perl book you're looking at, yes, you have to use `eval` with a string argument:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

my $cards = "K";
my $str = "A12K34567890JQK";
my $count = eval "\$str =~ tr/$cards//";
say $count;
```

will produce `2` (With no warnings on 5.22 or 5.32; don't have 5.26 installed anywhere to confirm with it). Note having to escape the `$` in the variable the `tr` operates on in the string so it isn't interpolated first.

---

You can do this without the potentially-dangerous `eval`, though, using `s//`:

```perl
my $count = $str =~ s/[\Q$cards\E]//g;
```

Comment: I like it, but "potentially-dangerous" could be converted to something more positive. It _is_ the "throw/catch" we have in perl so why not promote it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo `eval` of a string with variable interpolation done first *is* potentially dangerous if the variable comes from an untrusted/unvetted source. I agree with tadman's comments on the top level question.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, Re "*It* is *the "throw/catch" we have in perl*", It is not. Just like the OP, you're confusing `eval BLOCK` (the throw/catch of Perl, which is safe to use) and `eval EXPR` (code compiler and evaluator).

Comment: @ikegami Oups... I didn't notice the missing  parts even rhough I use `eval { somerhing potentially dying; }; if($@) { ... }` a lot myself.